# GoogleVis on shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I have the following code for my data set, Det,

ui.R

```
library(googleVis)

library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Visualization Tool"),
  sidebarLayout(
    #headerPanel('Data Selection'),
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput('x', 'X Variable', choices = c("Demand", "CapacityWeek", "EstTotal", "NewTotal")),
      selectInput('y', 'Y Variable', choices = c("Demand", "CapacityWeek", "EstTotal", "NewTotal")),
      selectInput('w', 'Size', choices = c("Demand", "CapacityWeek", "EstTotal", "NewTotal")),
      selectInput('z', 'colour', choices = c("PHYSICIAN","NURSE PRACTIONER")),
      dateRangeInput("Date", label = h3("Date range"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  datasetInput <- reactive({Det[Det$Position %in% input$Position,]})

  output$chart <- renderPlot({

    M <- gvisMotionChart(Det, idvar="Clinic", timevar="Date", xvar=input$x, yvar=input$y,

                    colour=input$z, sizevar=input$w)
    plot(M)

        })

})
```

It doesn't give me an error but it is not plotting the motion chart. Please kindly tell me what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `renderGvis` instead of `renderPlot` in your `server.R` file.

Comment: I ran into your question, because I'm having the same problem. I note in your `ui.R` your output is "plot", but in your `server.R` your output is "chart".